# Use the function form of "use strict". angularjs authentication (with scala, play framework)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, playframework

I'm trying to implement an example of authentication in my play application (with scala). I'm following this [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx)

So in the views folder I created the index page for authentication. and added this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')


    .controller('LoginController',
        ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

            $scope.login = function () {
                $scope.dataLoading = true;
                AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
                    if(response.success) {
                        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                        $location.path('/');
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = response.message;
                        $scope.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
            };
        }]);
```

and this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')

.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

            /* Dummy authentication for testing, uses $timeout to simulate api call
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            $timeout(function(){
                var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
                if(!response.success) {
                    response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                }
                callback(response);
            }, 1000);


            /* Use this for real authentication
             ----------------------------------------------*/
            //$http.post('/api/authenticate', { username: username, password: password })
            //    .success(function (response) {
            //        callback(response);
            //    });

        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        };

        return service;
    }])

.factory('Base64', function () {
    /* jshint ignore:start */

    var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

    return {
        encode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            do {
                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;

                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }

                output = output +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        },

        decode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
            var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
            if (base64test.exec(input)) {
                window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                    "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                    "Expect errors in decoding.");
            }
            input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

            do {
                enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

                if (enc3 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                }
                if (enc4 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                }

                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        }
    };

    /* jshint ignore:end */
});
```

and finaly this:

```
'use strict';

// declare modules
angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);

angular.module('BasicHttpAuthExample', [
    'Authentication',
    'Home',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in
            if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

to assets/javascripts/app folder and reference them in my main with this:

```
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/app/controllers.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/app/services.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/app/app.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm new to all of this I don't know if did I miss something or something else.
the error That I get is :

```
Use the function form of "use strict".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the code with "use strict" inside a function. So instead of

```
"use strict";
angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);
// (...)
```

use this instead

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('Authentication', []);
    angular.module('Home', []);
    // (...)
})();
```

You can also make JSHint ignore that error

```
/*jshint -W097 */
"use strict";

angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);
// (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the function form of "use strict".

What this is trying to tell you is not to put `"use strict"` at the top level scope in your file. It's saying to use it *within a function* instead. You can do that by wrapping your code in a scoping function, see the top and bottom line:

```
(function() { // The beginning of the scoping function

    'use strict';

    angular.module('Authentication')


    .controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

            $scope.login = function() {
                $scope.dataLoading = true;
                AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                        $location.path('/');
                    } else {
                        $scope.error = response.message;
                        $scope.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    ]);
})(); // The end of the function and the () to invoke it
```

Now, that `"use strict"` only applies within that function and its contents.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation